# Count whether a value exist from a range of keys

Tags: mysql

Return a count when response_val=4 is found between response_key 95 to 98 corresponding to each uhid and group by month

```
|response_key  | response_val | month  | uhid |
|---------------------------------------------|
|  95          |  4           | 2019-09| 14569|
|  96          |  4           | 2019-09| 14569|
|  97          |  5           | 2019-09| 14569|
|  98          |  5           | 2019-09| 14569|
|  95          |  5           | 2019-09| 13256|
|  96          |  5           | 2019-09| 13256|
|  97          |  5           | 2019-09| 13256|
|  98          |  5           | 2019-09| 13256|
|  95          |  5           | 2019-09| 25689|
|  96          |  5           | 2019-09| 25689|
|  97          |  5           | 2019-09| 25689|
|  98          |  5           | 2019-09| 25689|
|---------------------------------------------|
```

I tried sql query as

```
SELECT month,
       COUNT(CASE
          WHEN `response_key` IN (95,96,97,98) and `response_val`='5'
          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'yes',
       COUNT(CASE
          WHEN `response_key` IN (81,82,83,84,85,86,87) and `response_val`='4'
          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'no' 
FROM audit WHERE group by month
```

but it return the count when all the response_key have value 4.

I expect result as

```
| count | month |
-----------------
|   1   |2019-09|
```

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: Maybe you will find parts of the [SO help sections](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) useful for formatting your code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will get you what you want:

```
SELECT `month`, 
       COUNT(CASE response_val WHEN 4 THEN 1 END) AS `yes`,
       COUNT(CASE response_val WHEN 5 THEN 1 END) AS `no`
FROM audit
WHERE response_key between 95 AND 98
GROUP BY `month`
```

I simplified your case statements and move the `response_key` condition into the `where`-clause (the `ELSE` part in a `CASE` statement is only necessary if you want to return a value other than `null`).

You can find a working demo here: https://rextester.com/PCN24609

The resulting counts  from this query are:

```
month      yes     no
2019-09    1       11
```

Well, you can swap the order of your output columns as you like, and if you are only interested in the `response_val=4` counts do it like here:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE response_val WHEN 4 THEN 1 END) AS `count`,
       `month`
FROM audit
WHERE response_key between 95 AND 98
GROUP BY `month`
```

demo: https://rextester.com/JEV40175

result:

```
| count | month   |
-------------------
|     1 | 2019-09 |
```

**Edit**:

> "Return a count when response_val=4 is found between response_key 95
>   to 98 corresponding to each uhid and group by month"

This would imply that you simply group over `uhid` too, like shown here:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE response_val WHEN 4 THEN 1 END) AS `count`,
           `month`,uhid
FROM audit
WHERE response_key between 95 AND 98
GROUP BY `month`,uhid;

-- results:
count   month   uhid
0       2019-09 13256
2       2019-09 14569
1       2019-09 25689
```

Or, if you want all `uhid`-counts in one row per month:

```
SELECT `month`,
       COUNT(CASE uhid WHEN 14569 THEN 1 END) AS `cnt_14569`,
       COUNT(CASE uhid WHEN 13256 THEN 1 END) AS `cnt_13256`,
       COUNT(CASE uhid WHEN 25689 THEN 1 END) AS `cnt_25689`
FROM audit
WHERE response_key between 95 AND 98 AND response_val=4
GROUP BY `month`,uhid

-- results:
month   cnt_14569   cnt_13256   cnt_25689
2019-09         2           0           0
2019-09         0           0           1
```

demo: https://rextester.com/WXQ73318

**2. Edit:** Following your latest comment, the following might fulfil your requirements
("list the number of distinct users with `response_val=4` for each month"):

```
SELECT COUNT(`count`) usrcnt, `month` FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(CASE response_val WHEN 4 THEN 1 END) AS `count`,`month`,uhid
 FROM audit WHERE response_key between 95 AND 98
 GROUP BY `month`,uhid
) tbl WHERE `count`>0 GROUP BY `month`;

-- or, even shorter:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE response_val WHEN 4 THEN uhid END) AS `count`,`month`
FROM audit WHERE response_key between 95 AND 98
GROUP BY `month`;

-- same result from both queries:
usrcnt  month
     2  2019-09
```

demo: https://rextester.com/UGN73913

The latest queries are based on these table values:

```
response_key   response_val    month    uhid
          95              4  2019-09   14569
          96              4  2019-09   14569
          97              5  2019-09   14569
          98              5  2019-09   14569
          95              5  2019-09   13256
          96              5  2019-09   13256
          97              5  2019-09   13256
          98              5  2019-09   13256
          95              5  2019-09   25689
          96              4  2019-09   25689
          97              5  2019-09   25689
          98              5  2019-09   25689
```

Comment: but i want the count of uhid that contains response_val=4 in the range of response_key from 95 to 98

Comment: From the above result it returns the total count of 4 in the table.

Comment: @RinaXavier what does it mean **want the count of uhid that contains response_val=4**

Comment: from the above table,uhid 14569 and 25689 contains response_val=4.So count returns 2.if any other uhid contains response_val=4 between the range from 95 to 98 the count will increases.

Comment: @RinaXavier, do you mean you want the *total* count of distinct users that issued a `response_val=4` for a certain month? In that case, have a look again at my edited post.